Как сменить версию OpenMP C++ в компиляторе MSVS C++
Столкнулся с проблемой что компилятор MSVS 2022 не видит атрибут collapse() и пишет что игнорирует их. Узнал что это похоже связано с тем, что по умолчанию используется версия OpenMP 2.0.
Узнал, что нужно как-то поставить флаг /openmp:llvm
Вопрос: Как и где его поставить? В debug properties в разделе Language есть OpenMP support, но там только обычный /openmp и если поставить другой, то выдаёт ошибку.
